# Addressing issue of MySQL table size limit

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with huge amount of data and very frequently added rows.

If in future, table size limit reached then how to handle this problem? What is the maximum size of MySQL database table?

Comment: Why not ask Facebook? https://code.facebook.com/posts/190251048047090/myrocks-a-space-and-write-optimized-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

> If in future, table size limit reached then how to handle this
> problem?

You could use partitioning

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html

> **What is the maximum size of MySQL database table?**
>
> The effective maximum table size for MySQL databases is usually
> determined by operating system constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL
> internal limits. For up-to-date information operating system file size
> limits, refer to the documentation specific to your operating system.

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html